# Exclude fields from entities in Korma

Tags: sql, clojure, korma

I have some tables with a lot of columns where I sometimes need to just exclude 5-6 out of 50-60. Yes my tables are 3NF normalised, yes some have even more than 60 columns, if this sounds weird to you dear reader, try modelling biological entities.

To my question:

Is it possible to exclude fields by default in selects in Korma instead of specifying tens of columns in `entity-fields` at entity definition?

Comment: what kind of db? postgresql?

Comment: Yes, I'm on postgresql 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql to get all columns and generate `entity-fields`:

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = '<name of table>';
```

It's better to not select unused fields than filter them later.

Answer (score 1):

Based on googling this is not easily done in plain SQL which makes it somewhat difficult to do on the application-level as well.

Is it a problem that you receive the full payload from the database? If it is not then you could just add a post-processing function that drops the unwanted fields.

```
user=> (def unwanted-columns [:foo :bar])
#'user/unwanted-columns
user=> (map #(apply dissoc % unwanted-columns) [{:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3}])
({:baz 3})
```

Comment: This is how I currently do it. I wanted to see if a better solution exists. Thanks.

Comment: The very 2nd arguemnt to select is the field selector. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: @TommiKyntola, the author doesn't want to list 50-55 different columns in the select clause, just the 5-10 that are _not_ desired.